# Multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to read specific values from multi dimensional array using php below is the array. I want to read values of `[itemBody][div][0][p]`.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [toolName] => Eqiat
            [toolVersion] => 0.7~git
            [adaptive] => false
            [timeDependent] => false
            [identifier] => ITEM_b95e4391e33aa28561b01493b6e328f8
            [title] => match the following
        )

    [stylesheet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [href] => http://gauss.ecs.soton.ac.uk/eqiat/eqiat.css
                    [type] => text/css
                    [title] => Eqiat item styles, designed to override QTIEngine's output where appropriate
                )

        )

    [responseDeclaration] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_0
                            [cardinality] => multiple
                            [baseType] => identifier
                        )

                    [correctResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [value] => question_0_option_3
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_1
                            [cardinality] => multiple
                            [baseType] => identifier
                        )

                    [correctResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [value] => question_1_option_2
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_2
                            [cardinality] => multiple
                            [baseType] => identifier
                        )

                    [correctResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [value] => question_2_option_1
                        )

                )

            [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_3
                            [cardinality] => multiple
                            [baseType] => identifier
                        )

                    [correctResponse] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [value] => question_3_option_0
                        )

                )

        )

    [outcomeDeclaration] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [identifier] => SCORE
                    [cardinality] => single
                    [baseType] => integer
                )

            [defaultValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [value] => 0
                )

        )

    [itemBody] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [div] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [p] => Match The Following
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [class] => eqiat-emi
                                )

                            [ol] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [class] => emioptions
                                        )

                                    [li] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => bangalore
                                            [1] => india
                                            [2] => tiger
                                            [3] => onion
                                        )

                                )

                            [choiceInteraction] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [maxChoices] => 0
                                                    [minChoices] => 0
                                                    [shuffle] => false
                                                    [responseIdentifier] => RESPONSE_question_0
                                                )

                                            [prompt] => vegetable
                                            [simpleChoice] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => A
                                                    [1] => B
                                                    [2] => C
                                                    [3] => D
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [maxChoices] => 0
                                                    [minChoices] => 0
                                                    [shuffle] => false
                                                    [responseIdentifier] => RESPONSE_question_1
                                                )

                                            [prompt] => animal
                                            [simpleChoice] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => A
                                                    [1] => B
                                                    [2] => C
                                                    [3] => D
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [maxChoices] => 0
                                                    [minChoices] => 0
                                                    [shuffle] => false
                                                    [responseIdentifier] => RESPONSE_question_2
                                                )

                                            [prompt] => country
                                            [simpleChoice] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => A
                                                    [1] => B
                                                    [2] => C
                                                    [3] => D
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [maxChoices] => 0
                                                    [minChoices] => 0
                                                    [shuffle] => false
                                                    [responseIdentifier] => RESPONSE_question_3
                                                )

                                            [prompt] => city
                                            [simpleChoice] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => A
                                                    [1] => B
                                                    [2] => C
                                                    [3] => D
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [responseProcessing] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [setOutcomeValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [identifier] => SCORE
                        )

                    [baseValue] => 0
                )

            [responseCondition] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [responseIf] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [match] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_0
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [correct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_0
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [setOutcomeValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                )

                                            [sum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [baseValue] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [responseIf] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [match] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [correct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_1
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [setOutcomeValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                )

                                            [sum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [baseValue] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [responseIf] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [match] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_2
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [correct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_2
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [setOutcomeValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                )

                                            [sum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [baseValue] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [responseIf] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [match] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_3
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [correct] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => RESPONSE_question_3
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [setOutcomeValue] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                        (
                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                )

                                            [sum] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                (
                                                    [variable] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                                        (
                                                            [@attributes] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [identifier] => SCORE
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [baseValue] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: It is an object not array. Convert to array and access the value.

Comment: So did you give up or one of these solved it???

Comment: thanks For your help i got this working below is my solution
function object2array($object) { 
    return json_decode(json_encode($object), true); 
  }

$data = object2array(simplexml_load_string($xml1));

echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';

//echo $data[itembody][div][0][p];

       echo $data[itemBody][div][0][p];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert the complete object in to array and then access

```
 ' function object2array($object) { '
  return json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

}
$data = object2array(simplexml_load_string($xml1));

echo '

```
',print_r($data),'
```

';`

Now i can access by `echo $data[itemBody][div][0][p];`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$element = $object->itemBody->div->0->p;
```

Comment: i convert it to array as it was object and then can access by  ' function object2array($object) { '
      return json_decode(json_encode($object), true); 
  }
$data = object2array(simplexml_load_string($xml1));

echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';`


Now i can access by `echo $data[itemBody][div][0][p];`

Answer (score 0):

That is an object and `itemBody` is a property that holds another object with a property `div` which is an array of objects with properties, `p` being one for the object at array index `0`:

```
$result = $object->itemBody->div[0]->p;
```